# Dynamically set class in anchor doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, anchor

I have been trying to dynamically adding a class name into anchors but somehow it does not work. My codes are:

HTML:

```
<div class="list-group" id="setActive">
    <a href="#">aaa</a>
    <a href="#">bbb</a>
    <a href="#">ccc</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var setActive = document.getElementById('setActive'),
    var anchor = setActive.getElementsByTagName('a'),

    for (var i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++) {

        anchor[i].className = "list-item";
    }
 }
```

Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: The commas `,` trailing each `var` declaration should be semicolons `;`. They're creating SyntaxErrors since the parser is expecting another variable to follow and is instead finding the keywords `var` and `for`.

Comment: The `)` for `.ready()` is also missing from what you posted. Fixing those, it should work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/1f93mup7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Refer to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jjbdrzp5/4/**

The main reason your code isn't working is sytax errors. Here it is cleaned up:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var setActive = document.getElementById('setActive'),
        anchor = setActive.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++) {
        anchor[i].className = "list-item";
    }

 });
```

However you can do this all with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#setActive a').addClass('list-item');
});
```

Also make sure you're correctly mapping the $ sign to jQuery in your JS file:

```
(function($) {
    // docready etc etc here
}(jQuery));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Though all the other answers are great too but I think the syntax errors are the major problems in my case. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

As I see you are using jQuery there, so you can simplify your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( '#setActive a' ).addClass( 'list-item' );
});
```

Comment: Tried this, for some reasons the "list-item" is not set whatsoever

Comment: Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jjbdrzp5/ - if this didn't work for you, it's likely that you have a different problem.

Comment: Works fine for me. See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/41g5fc4w/ Are you sure you have connected jQuery to your page?

Comment: @antyrat haha, almost identical fiddles :-)

Comment: Yea it works on fiddle but does anyone know why my original codes don't work? I did it that way because I might need to set class to specific anchors later. Thanks!

Comment: Look into console, maybe there is some errors, show us more code or provide fiddle too. It's hard to say

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        anchors[i].className = "list-item";
    }
 }
```

This will give you an array of all the anchor tags that are present in the DOM.

Comment: Yes but the problem is on my webpage I have a whole bunch of other anchors that I don't want to set. That's why I specified an ID.

Comment: Then the answer given by Benjamin should do it.

Answer (score 0):

no need for Jquery for this just use dom selectors like this

```
var setActive = document.getElementById('setActive'),
    anchors = setActive.querySelectorAll('a');
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++)
    anchors[i].className = "list-item";
```

you have different type of issues with your code, first you need to finish declaration with ; not , and even if you want to use , you don't have to start with var again.

if you are only using JQuery to check dom load you can skip  it with this.

[demo here JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omarqa/zysqx8dc/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't seem to want to use jQuery, here is a native version, you just had a few minor syntax errors, the code was generally fine! I changed some things to how I would do it but the general structure is intact

http://jsfiddle.net/jjbdrzp5/3/

HTML

```
<div class="list-group" id="setActive">
    <a href="#">aaa</a>
    <a href="#">bbb</a>
    <a href="#">ccc</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.list-item {
    color: red;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var setActive = document.querySelector('#setActive'),
        anchors = setActive.querySelectorAll('a');

    [].forEach.call(anchors, function(anchor) {
        anchor.classList.add("list-item");
    });

});
```